# Get index for minimum value

Tags: vb.net, arraylist, indexing, minimum

I'm trying to find the index of the minimum value inside an Array List in `VB.net`. I'll then use this index to split two array list at the same location.

I found the minimum value, but can't figure out how to get this value index.

```
Dim smallest As Double = Double.MaxValue

For Each element As Double In MyArray
    smallest = Math.Min(smallest, element)
Next

Dim splitpoint = MyArray.IndexOf(smallest)

Console.WriteLine(smallest)
Console.WriteLine(splitpoint)
```

I get a result of -1 for split point which is not right. I'm sure this isn't the most efficient way to find the min value using with a loop.

Any help would me massive.
Thanks

Comment: If you ditch the antiquated ArrayList and use something like a List you can use the `Min` and `Max` extension methods

Comment: That was an awesome comment. I got it. Using List worked with `Dim splitpoint as Interger = MyArray.IndexOf(MyArray.Min)`